# Stop redirecting when refresh page in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**I am using react-router-dom**

Below I have attached my code

```
 let route =
    <Switch>
     <Route path="/support_login/:token" component={SupportLogin}/>
     <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
     <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
    <LandingPageLayout>
        <Route path="/" component ={Landingpge}/>
        <Redirect to="/"/>
    </LandingPageLayout>
   </Switch>
 if(props.token){
   route = <Layout>
     <Route path="/logout" component={Logout}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/packages" exact component={Packages}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/payments" exact component={Payments}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/billings" exact component={Billings}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/snapshots" exact component={Snapshots}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/vpn_servers" exact component={VpnServers}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/cloud_servers" exact component={CloudServer}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/profile" exact component={Profile}/>
     <Route path={`/dashboard/server_details/:server_id`} exact component={ServerDetails}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/create_vpn_server" exact component={CreateVpnServer}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard/create_cloud_server" exact component={CreateCloudServer}/>
     <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard}/>
     <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
   </Layout>
  }
```

Now if refresh any route from the browser, I am redirecting to "dashboard"  or "/" based on the token. But If I remove  it works. But when I have a false URL found, I need to be redirected. Now, How may I achieve this?
How to stop redirecting to root or "/dashboard", if I refresh any page?

What I need is, if I reload or refresh a page from a browser, I want to be redirected to the path I was before refreshing or reloading. Rather than redirecting to "/" or "dashboard"

I am in

```
<Route path="/dashboard/create_cloud_server" exact component= 
 {CreateCloudServer}/>
```

and I refresh the URL from the browser or reload it, It redirecting me to

```
<Redirect to="/dashboard"/> 
//or if not token
 <Redirect to="/"/>
```

But I want to get to the original path this one below, as it was the path before reloading url.

```
<Route path="/dashboard/create_cloud_server" exact component= 
 {CreateCloudServer}/>
```

Comment: Sorry, remove *what* and your code works? The token check? the `Redirect`? What is a false URL and when is it found? Please include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a bit more detail around the issue.

Comment: I have added redirection 2 paths, one if there is a token, another is if no token. False URL means if URL doesn't exist.  . Ok let me explain. In react when I refresh/reload a page from a browser, it redirects to "/", but it should redirect me to the original path. It should redirect me to the path i was, before the refresh.

Comment: I see, "False URL" means a path that doesn't match any routes and falls through to the redirect. Is `this.props.token` available on the initial render? Sounds like it isn't and loaded/checked when the component mounts, thus it isn't available until *at least* the second render. By then the path check has occurred and you're already bounced out. Seems you need a "loading" or "pending" state while the token value/check is resolved. Can you include the minimal, reproducible example for us to inspect?

Comment: useEffect(()=>{
    props.onAuthCheck()
    getGateway()
  
  },[])

Comment: I am using use effect to check auth check, should I use async-await for this.

Comment: Below i have added my app.js page

Comment: `useEffect` hook callbacks are 100% synchronous. Does `onAuthCheck` and/or `onAddGateway` actions eventually update the `state.auth.token` value for the token check in the UI? Can you walk us through the (or what you expect them to be) sequence of events/actions, starting from `App` mounting, on through to a route being rendered?